# The code inside $.getJSON() is not executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I can't figure out what is wrong here.

```
$(function() {
    $('#cars').change(function() {
        var cars = $('#cars').val();
            $.getJSON('http://fooobar.com/data.php?id='+cars, function(data) {
                    alert('test');
        });
    });
});
```

Request to http://fooobar.com/data.php?id=3 returns json string like this

```
 [{1: "sdadd"}]
```

The problems is that code

```
alert('test');
```

is not executed when request to data.php returns correct json string but is executed when no data is returned.

What I miss ?

Comment: The [same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) applies. You cannot retrieve JSON from an external domain. It should be JSONP then.

Answer (score 3):

```
[{1: "sdadd"}]
```

is not a correct JSON string. You can't have numbers as `keys` in objects and these keys can't start with a number.
That's why jQuery doesn't execute your `success` callback:

```
jQuery.getJSON( url [, data] [, success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)] )
```

According to the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/):

> As of jQuery 1.4, if the JSON file contains a syntax error, the request will usually fail silently

You can try this to check if I'm right:

```
jQuery.getJSON(...).error(function() { alert("error"); })
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess it's the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), which stops a webpage calling AJAX on another domain.

Comment: Incorrect. The data is returned there, but it has JSON format instead of JSONP, hence no callback function is called.

Comment: So that would be the Same Origin Policy

Answer (score 0):

You are using incorrect format to do a cross domain data request.
You need to do return JSONP data, not JSON .
For JSONP to work, your URL :

http://fooobar.com/data.php?id=3

which normally returns `{ "result" : "some data" }`

when called with any callback function name ,eg :

http://fooobar.com/data.php?id=3&callback=myJavascriptFunction
should return :  `myJavascriptFunction( { "result" : "some data" } )`
only then it can call your callback javascript function with JSON data.

example:
see the out of these two api calls to facebook api which supports JSONP format :

i) JSON :

https://graph.facebook.com/19292868552

ii) JSONP :

https://graph.facebook.com/19292868552?callback=myFunctionName

Read more here : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Answer (score 0):

Same origin policy is the problem here, as others have said.

But here's what they didn't say - how to fix it:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "someurl.com",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    data: {'some key':'somevalue', 'someotherkey':'val'},
    success: function(response) { alert(response); },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
        //do some error handling
        alert(jqXHR);
        alert(textStatus);
        alert(errorThrown);
    } 
});
```

Here I'm using the `$.ajax` method - basically `$.getJSON` is a wrapper for this with `dataType:'json'`.

Note: this will change your request so that it passes in a param called "callback" which will be completely random. This needs to be processed by the server and passed back as a function name: i.e

Your request:

```
someurl.com/?something=something&callback=123456
```

Should return:

```
123456({ "key":"value"});
```

And that *should* allow you to get the returned data as normal.

Reference:
The bit on JSONP and the various options that can be used in $.ajax is quite good here:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Wikipedia has an alright article on it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#Padding

Edit: also doing the request like this and using an error function will allow you to throw any errors to the console or alert boxes, so you can check if your returned JSON is valid or not too. Markup edited to throw an alert box on failure.